# Subclasses missing in Eclipse-generated WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to set up a web service.

My approach has been:

- create Dynamic Web Project
- create class "MyService":

  ```
  @WebService
  @XmlSeeAlso({B.class})
  public class MyService {
      public A method() {
          return new B();
      }
  }
  ```
- create class "A":

  ```
  @XmlSeeAlso(B.class)
  public class A {
      public int propertyOfA=0;
  }
  ```
- create class "B":

  ```
  public class B extends A {
      public int propertyOfB=1;
  }
  ```
- Create Web Service from MyService.java

There are no errors, all the files get created. However, the class B does not appear anywhere in the WSDL. Consequently, all web service responses never contain any values for `propertyOfB`, as it's not in the service description.

How do I get `B` into the WSDL?

edit: I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm creating the web service for Tomcat v7.0, Apache Axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement is to inform the user of the web service that B type object can also be returned form the method() operation. So what you have to do is adding a entry like this to your service.xml,

```
 <parameter name="extraClass">B</parameter>
```

So it will add entries to WSDL mentioning the web service operation will return these kind of object also. So when code-gen happens these are also generated. You can find which class is returned by checking the xsi:type of the response. Please read this blog for further understanding, http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-get-best-use-of-axis2-object.html

Comment: I'm unsure where to put that line. There is no service.xml file anywhere in my project. The files deploy.wsdd and server-config.wsdd do look like it might make sense to put the line somewhere in there. Doing so does not result in an error, but it does not change the server's response.

Comment: server-config.wsdd was the place to put it. Just a minor spelling error: `<parameter name="extraClasses" value="my.package.B">` did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more comment. This did not change the WSDL generated within Eclipse. But after deployment, the WSDL generated by the server contained everything I wanted.